# Integer functional equation $f(f(f(n)))=f(n+1)+1$

Tags: functional-equations

Can you find all functions $f:\mathbb N\rightarrow\mathbb N$ satisfying the functional equation
$$
f(f(f(n)))=f(n+1)+1
$$

Comment: Are you saying that the equation only needs to be satisfied for $n>0$, but $f$ can take any values in $\mathbb N$, positive or negative or 0?

Comment: If you assume $f(n)$ is polynomial, then you can show that $f(n)=n+1$. In fact, you can rule out any function such that $f(n)\to \infty$ that doesn't do so linearly.

Comment: There is a solution here:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1122390/olympiad-style-question-about-functions-satisfying-condition-fffn-fn1

Answer (score 1):

The set of valid functions is given by $$ f(n) = \begin{cases}  n+1 & n \text{ even} \\  n+5 & n \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \\  n-3 & n \equiv 3 \pmod 4. \end{cases}$$ and $f(n)=n+1$. Solutions can be found [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h597123p3543371) and the official solution can be found [here](https://www.imo-official.org/problems/IMO2013SL.pdf) (this is a download link).